# Change view appearance inside a Popover?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

How do you change the appearance of your views inside a popover? Say I have Master-Detail with a top search bar that is gray in horizontal view, but when it's in vertical view inside a popover, I want it to be glossy black to match the popover appearance.

Where would I put this code?

I am tempted to put it in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` or `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` or `willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, since no one has any opinion, I ended putting it inside `willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and seems to be working fine.